# Set visibility to channels members on video upload to youtube data api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I do want to automate my upload of videos for my members. I followed the tutorial I found here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

There I can set a "privacyStatus", but this field is missing a value for "channel members". Using the UI (studio.youtube.com) this can be made by clicking on the video and setting the visibility to channel members only.

How can this be done using the Youtube Data API?

Answer (score 0):

The youtube data api is very old and has not been updated to support these features.  you could report it as a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)  if its not there already.